# Home button, recent button, notifications, pull down menu all stopped working

Tags: notifications, recents-screen, home-button, nexus

I have a Nexus 9 running Android 7.1.1, and the home button, recent button, *all* notifications, and the top pull-down menu all stopped working.

The home and recent buttons respond to being tapped in that the animation that indicates I tapped them runs (the gray circle expands out from the button), but nothing happens. I can open the top pull-down menu, but it always says that there are no notifications, and I can't pull the menu down further to expand the icons.

I have about 15 GB out of about 30 GB available, and memory usage is listed at 1.6 GB out of 1.8 GB. I've tried restarting the device multiple times.

If I remember correctly, I accidentally drained the battery before this happened, but I can't recall if the device was simply powered off. When I powered up the device, the PIN prompt buttons caused the device to vibrate, even though I had had previously had that setting turned off. I restarted the device, and that setting turned back off. Double-tapping to wake up the device doesn't work consistently.

Any ideas?

Comment: May be the SystemUI crashed? Try flash it (or full ROM)

Comment: Can you help me figure out how to do that? Messing around with Android is not something I know anything about. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: How to flash? If you don't have a PC you should got root access, then unlock bootloader (if locked), find and flash recovery for you device like CWM or TWRP (Rashr app), download ROM for your device and flash it from recovery. If you have PC you can flash with FlashTool. Sorry for my little english ;)

Comment: It looks like there's a Linux version of FlashTool, so I'll give that a try from my Chromebook (running GalliumOS). No worries about the English. It's perfectly fine! Will it be obvious which ROM I need?

Comment: I like the LineageOS project. You can choose ROM on xda-forum. But I recommend LOS (https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.xda-developers.com/official-lineageos-14-1-builds-for-the-google-nexus-9/amp/)